# Vue.js Multiple Filters in Multiple Modals

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuex

I built a CRUD app using Vue.js and Flask. I am also using axios. My application has a single component which gets data from a database and displays it in a table. The base path gets all records from a database at:

```
localhost:5000/expenses
```

I created two buttons that filter the data using modals. The first modal takes a start date and an end date, and when submitted does a get request at:

```
localhost:5000/expense?startDate=2020-04-10&endDate=2020-04-2
```

Flask then queries the data filtering by the date range and returns the data to the table.

The second modal allows you to choose a category from a drop down, and does another get request. However, this request does not persist the previous get request and only queries the backend at:

```
localhost:5000/expense?category=food
```

Unless reset, I would like the get request to filter by both, i.e:

```
localhost:5000/expense?startDate=2020-04-10&endDate=2020-04-21&category=food
```

My get request is a method that can take 3 named parameters:

```
getExpenses({  
  filteredCategory,  
  filteredStartDate,  
  filteredEndDate,  
} = {}) {  
  const path = 'http://localhost:5000/expenses';  
  axios.get(path, {  
    params: {  
      category: filteredCategory,  
      startDate: filteredStartDate,  
      endDate: filteredEndDate,  
    },  
  })
```

And it is called independently when each modal is submitted:

```
onSubmitCategory(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.$refs.addCategoryModal.hide();
  const filteredCat = this.addCategoryForm.category;
  this.getExpenses({
    filteredCategory: filteredCat,
  });
  this.initForm();

onSubmitDate(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.$refs.addDateRangeModal.hide();
  const filtStartDate = this.addDateRangeForm.startDate;
  const filtEndDate = this.addDateRangeForm.endDate;
  this.getExpenses({
    filteredStartDate: filtStartDate,
    filteredEndDate: filtEndDate,
  });
  this.initForm();
```

What is the best way to ensure state is preserved and that I can filter on top of previously filtered data? Also, is there a way to preserve state when refreshing the webpage? It currently goes back to the base path and queries all data instead of preserving the last query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might use vue-router for more efficient way to handle querying.

I used `lodash` for cherrypick query

```
mounted() {
    this.getExpences();
},

methods: {
    // axios get function
    getExpences() {
        axios.get(path, this.getRequestQuery()).then((res) => {
             // Some response handling code here
        }).catch((e) => {
             // Some error handling code here
        })
    },

    // Call search on filter change event or put filters in form and call search on submit event
    search() {
        const query = this.mapFiltersToQuery();
        this.$router.push({ query });
    },

    // get query from $route.query + filters and create query for request
    getRequestQuery() {
        this.mapQueryToFilters();
        const query = this.mapFiltersToQuery();
        return query;
    },

    // combine queries from $route.query and your filters in your data
    mapQueryToFilters() {
        this.filters = { ...this.filters, this.$route.query };
    },

    // cherrypick from filters in data
    mapFiltersToQuery() {
        const nonEmptyFilters = _.pickBy(this.filters, v => (!_.isEmpty(v) || !!v));
        return nonEmptyFilters;
    },
},

watch: {
    '$route.query': {
        handler() {
            this.getExpences();
        },
        deep: true,
    }
}
```

Goodluck